# Why the Dynamic Templates of Meteor need session variables?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I wonder how the Dynamic Templates of Meteor work. I've read several articles, questions and documentation. Know how to use but do not understand how it works. Why do you need a variable session to work? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Session`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session) is basically the answer to "Which scope am I going to pollute again to store this data?".

It's just a namespace. You put data in it. You could almost do the very same thing by defining a global object, except that every data stored in `Session` is a [`Reactive-Var`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar), meaning that when this data changes, all [reactive computations](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker) are invalidated and re-ran; and the [template helpers](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers) happen to be reactive computations!

So when you see any example using `Session`, it's just to keep the code clear and avoid using something like `var reactiveText = new ReactiveVar();`.

It slightly goes out of the scope of your question, but my advice to train would be to try to ditch some of the `Session` things you see in the examples and try to replace them with locally-scoped Reactive variables, to try yourself at it. And maybe do some stuff with `Tracker.autorun`.

Comment: I Got You! Many Thanks! I'll follow your training. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `Session` at all to build a reactive application. Templates with data sources (mongoDB queries that return a cursor) are enough.

That doesn't mean `Session` isn't useful, it can be very useful, but its use is not *required*.